# ogr2ogr import fgdb to postgis and prefix added table name

Tags: ogr2ogr

I have multiple fgdb with many feature classes.

I am importing them to my PostGIS and this is the code i used

> ogr2ogr -overwrite -progress -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres^" MY.gdb

Yet the table names in my PostGIS comes same as my fgdb feature classes.
I want to add prefix when I am importing them to PostGIS
like "buliding" feature class in FGDB becomes Test_building in PostGIS

"-nln" option does not seem to have that function (or I just can't find?)

Answer (score 2):

The `-nln` option works on individual layers, so you would have to split your import into several commands

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -progress -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 
  dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres^" 
  MY.gdb building -nln Test_building
```

Alternatively, you can import the entire FGDB and rename the layers inside the PostgresDB; or you can create a `test` schema and import your tables, with the original names, in this specific schema.